# How can I stop OnClickListener in the middle of execution?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

I need to exit out of an OnClickListner event in the middle of its execution but, can't find a command to do so. Tried using break but that can only be used on for loops, I'm looking for a command that would just stop the execution process and not kill or finish the activity.

```
saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        amountEntered = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountEntered);
        Integer bal = Integer.parseInt(custBal);
        Integer enteredAmount = Integer.parseInt(amountEntered.getText().toString());

        // check if amount entered is more than the balance:
        if( enteredAmount > bal ){

            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MakePaymentActivity.this,R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
            alertDialog.setTitle("VERIFY AMOUNT");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Is entered amount correct?");
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Simply Exit here
                    }
                }
            );
        });
```

The other button (Positive Button) would just dismiss the dialog and continue saving.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following exactly what you're saying, but showing that `AlertDialog` is not going to stop the rest of the code executing in `saveBtn`'s `onClick()` method, if that's what you're thinking. The `AlertDialog` will show, and whatever else is in `saveBtn`'s `onClick()` will immediately continue, regardless of whatever `Button` the user eventually clicks. What you'd want to do is execute the save in the positive `Button` `onClick()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

just call alertDialog.[dismiss()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#cancel()) or alertDialog.[cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#cancel())

Comment: OP does not want to exit the dialog. He wants to stop a particular code from running.

Answer (score 1):

To stop a particular code from running in places, you use these keywords:

| Place to stop | Keyword |
| --- | --- |
| In a loop | `break;` to stop the loop from running again and not running the remains code `continue;` to stop the current round of the loop and proceed to the next one |
| In a while loop | `break;` to stop the while loop from running again and not running the remains code `continue;` to stop the current round of the while loop and proceed to the next one |
| **In a method** | **`return;` to stop the code from running further.** |

Here, we need to use the Second one from the table. This will stop the code from running further. Try this in your negative button:

```java
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        return; // <- Simply Exit here
                    }
                }
            );
```